# In R, how does one place multiple filled.contour() plots in a single device?

Tags: r

`layout()` doesn't cut it, since `filled.contour()` actually *uses* `layout()` to set up the main plot and the legend to the side.  I can always get my plots one by one and combine them with some graphics utility, but it would be more efficient to stay in R if I can.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `levelplot` from package `lattice`. You can get multiple panels, and the plots really look nice.

Look at figure 6.9 in chapter 6 of the Lattice book:

http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html

That way you are not stuck with hacking the filled contour code. ( I did try searching for something in the rhelp and SO archives and came up empty.)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the lattice book online, I hadnt seen it before. What a great resource!

Comment: Yes.The book is even better because it is a good look inside Sarkar's thinking process.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use *image()* and then use *layout()* . A legend must be manually added though.