# How does one turn contour lines into filled contours?

Tags: r, contour

Does anyone know of a way to turn the output of `contourLines` polygons in order to plot as filled contours, as with `filled.contours`. Is there an order to how the polygons must then be plotted in order to see all available levels? Here is an example snippet of code that doesn't work:

```
#typical plot
filled.contour(volcano, color.palette = terrain.colors)

#try
cont <- contourLines(volcano)
fun <- function(x) x$level
LEVS <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(cont, fun))))
COLS <- terrain.colors(length(LEVS))
contour(volcano)
for(i in seq(cont)){
    COLNUM <- match(cont[[i]]$level, LEVS)
    polygon(cont[[i]], col=COLS[COLNUM], border="NA")
}
contour(volcano, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: can not find a complete solution but using `contour(volcano, add=TRUE)` already solves part of your problems or?

Comment: thanks @thijsvandenbergh - I was hoping to get the actual polygons in order to try and project these onto another grid.

Comment: that i dont get but this might be of help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849623/in-r-how-does-one-place-multiple-filled-contour-plots-in-a-single-device)

Comment: So what is expected in your image? Other than missing a color for one polygon level, it looks reasonable. You might just need to check the values in `COLS` .  For debugging, try plotting just one `cont[[k]]` at a time to see if anything is noncopascetic.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I would like it to look like the `filled.contour` plot. There are a few problems: 1. the lowest contour should include the are to the corners - I suspect you are right that this is probably a matter of coding the levels correctly. 2. The center of the crater should have a level of 150, but it is over-layed by 160.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  The old "what to do with negative contours" problem :-(. If the source contour sets for 150 and 160 are single polygons, this is going to get messy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution that uses the `raster` package (which calls `rgeos` and `sp`). The output is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` that will cover every value in your grid:

```
library('raster')
rr <- raster(t(volcano))
rc <- cut(rr, breaks= 10)
pols <- rasterToPolygons(rc, dissolve=T)
spplot(pols)
```

[Here's a discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-geo@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg06316.html) that will show you how to simplify ('prettify') the resulting polygons.

[image]

Comment: Nicely answered -- one can see that the contours do go back down in the center, per comments above.  Tho' your color choice leaves one wondering :-) :-)

Comment: Thanks @Noah - this is a good approach. Been meaning to learn the functionality of the `raster` package anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to some inspiration from [this](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_SolutionCenter/gw_create_contour_polygons.htm) site, I worked up a function to convert contour lines to filled contours. It's set-up to process a raster object and return a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

```r
raster2contourPolys <- function(r, levels = NULL) {

  ## set-up levels
  levels <- sort(levels)
  plevels <- c(min(values(r), na.rm=TRUE), levels, max(values(r), na.rm=TRUE)) # pad with raster range
  llevels <- paste(plevels[-length(plevels)], plevels[-1], sep=" - ")  
  llevels[1] <- paste("<", min(levels))
  llevels[length(llevels)] <- paste(">", max(levels))

  ## convert raster object to matrix so it can be fed into contourLines
  xmin <- extent(r)@xmin
  xmax <- extent(r)@xmax
  ymin <- extent(r)@ymin
  ymax <- extent(r)@ymax
  rx <- seq(xmin, xmax, length.out=ncol(r))
  ry <- seq(ymin, ymax, length.out=nrow(r))
  rz <- t(as.matrix(r))
  rz <- rz[,ncol(rz):1] # reshape

  ## get contour lines and convert to SpatialLinesDataFrame
  cat("Converting to contour lines...\n")
  cl <- contourLines(rx,ry,rz,levels=levels) 
  cl <- ContourLines2SLDF(cl)

  ## extract coordinates to generate overall boundary polygon
  xy <- coordinates(r)[which(!is.na(values(r))),]
  i <- chull(xy)
  b <- xy[c(i,i[1]),]
  b <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(b, hole = FALSE)), "1")))

  ## add buffer around lines and cut boundary polygon
  cat("Converting contour lines to polygons...\n")
  bcl <- gBuffer(cl, width = 0.0001) # add small buffer so it cuts bounding poly
  cp <- gDifference(b, bcl)

  ## restructure and make polygon number the ID
  polys <- list() 
  for(j in seq_along(cp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons)) {
    polys[[j]] <- Polygons(list(cp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[j]]),j)
  }
  cp <- SpatialPolygons(polys)
  cp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(cp, data.frame(id=seq_along(cp)))

  ## cut the raster by levels
  rc <- cut(r, breaks=plevels)

  ## loop through each polygon, create internal buffer, select points and define overlap with raster
  cat("Adding attributes to polygons...\n")
  l <- character(length(cp))
  for(j in seq_along(cp)) {
    p <- cp[cp$id==j,] 
    bp <- gBuffer(p, width = -max(res(r))) # use a negative buffer to obtain internal points
    if(!is.null(bp)) {
      xy <- SpatialPoints(coordinates(bp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]))[1]
      l[j] <- llevels[extract(rc,xy)]
    } 
    else { 
      xy <- coordinates(gCentroid(p)) # buffer will not be calculated for smaller polygons, so grab centroid
      l[j] <- llevels[extract(rc,xy)]
    } 
  }

  ## assign level to each polygon
  cp$level <- factor(l, levels=llevels)
  cp$min <- plevels[-length(plevels)][cp$level]
  cp$max <- plevels[-1][cp$level]  
  cp <- cp[!is.na(cp$level),] # discard small polygons that did not capture a raster point
  df <- unique(cp@data[,c("level","min","max")]) # to be used after holes are defined
  df <- df[order(df$min),]
  row.names(df) <- df$level
  llevels <- df$level

  ## define depressions in higher levels (ie holes)
  cat("Defining holes...\n")
  spolys <- list()
  p <- cp[cp$level==llevels[1],] # add deepest layer
  p <- gUnaryUnion(p)
  spolys[[1]] <- Polygons(p@polygons[[1]]@Polygons, ID=llevels[1])
  for(i in seq(length(llevels)-1)) {
    p1 <- cp[cp$level==llevels[i+1],] # upper layer
    p2 <- cp[cp$level==llevels[i],] # lower layer
    x <- numeric(length(p2)) # grab one point from each of the deeper polygons
    y <- numeric(length(p2))
    id <- numeric(length(p2))
    for(j in seq_along(p2)) {
      xy <- coordinates(p2@polygons[[j]]@Polygons[[1]])[1,]
      x[j] <- xy[1]; y[j] <- xy[2]
      id[j] <- as.numeric(p2@polygons[[j]]@ID)
    }
    xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(x,y), data.frame(id=id))
    holes <- over(xy, p1)$id
    holes <- xy$id[which(!is.na(holes))]
    if(length(holes)>0) {
      p2 <- p2[p2$id %in% holes,] # keep the polygons over the shallower polygon
      p1 <- gUnaryUnion(p1) # simplify each group of polygons
      p2 <- gUnaryUnion(p2)
      p <- gDifference(p1, p2) # cut holes in p1      
    } else { p <- gUnaryUnion(p1) }
    spolys[[i+1]] <- Polygons(p@polygons[[1]]@Polygons, ID=llevels[i+1]) # add level 
  }
  cp <- SpatialPolygons(spolys, pO=seq_along(llevels), proj4string=CRS(proj4string(r))) # compile into final object
  cp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(cp, df)
  cat("Done!")
  cp

}
```

It probably holds several inefficiencies, but it has worked well in the tests I've conducted using bathymetry data. Here's an example using the volcano data:

```r
r <- raster(t(volcano))
l <- seq(100,200,by=10)
cp <- raster2contourPolys(r, levels=l)
cols <- terrain.colors(length(cp))
plot(cp, col=cols, border=cols, axes=TRUE, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
contour(r, levels=l, add=TRUE)
box()
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't bad, but not all polygons are spatially exclusive - try adding `plot(cp[4,], add=T, col='black')` - which will cause problems for both analysis and visualisation (requiring specific plot order, precluding transparency, etc). `gDifference` might be your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the excellent work of Paul Regular, here is a version that should ensure exclusive polygons (i.e. no overlapping).

I've added a new argument `fd` for *fairy dust* to address an issue I discovered working with UTM-type coordinates.  Basically as I understand the algorithm works by sampling lateral points from the contour lines to determine which side is *inside* the polygon.  The distance of the sample point from the line can create problems if it ends up in e.g. behind another contour. So if your resulting polygons looks wrong try setting `fd` to values 10^±n until it looks very wrong or about right..

```
raster2contourPolys <- function(r, levels = NULL, fd = 1) {
  ## set-up levels
  levels <- sort(levels)
  plevels <- c(min(values(r)-1, na.rm=TRUE), levels, max(values(r)+1, na.rm=TRUE)) # pad with raster range
  llevels <- paste(plevels[-length(plevels)], plevels[-1], sep=" - ")  
  llevels[1] <- paste("<", min(levels))
  llevels[length(llevels)] <- paste(">", max(levels))

  ## convert raster object to matrix so it can be fed into contourLines
  xmin <- extent(r)@xmin
  xmax <- extent(r)@xmax
  ymin <- extent(r)@ymin
  ymax <- extent(r)@ymax
  rx <- seq(xmin, xmax, length.out=ncol(r))
  ry <- seq(ymin, ymax, length.out=nrow(r))
  rz <- t(as.matrix(r))
  rz <- rz[,ncol(rz):1] # reshape

  ## get contour lines and convert to SpatialLinesDataFrame
  cat("Converting to contour lines...\n")
  cl0 <- contourLines(rx, ry, rz, levels = levels)
  cl <- ContourLines2SLDF(cl0)

  ## extract coordinates to generate overall boundary polygon
  xy <- coordinates(r)[which(!is.na(values(r))),]
  i <- chull(xy)
  b <- xy[c(i,i[1]),]
  b <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(b, hole = FALSE)), "1")))

  ## add buffer around lines and cut boundary polygon
  cat("Converting contour lines to polygons...\n")
  bcl <- gBuffer(cl, width = fd*diff(bbox(r)[1,])/3600000) # add small buffer so it cuts bounding poly
  cp <- gDifference(b, bcl)

  ## restructure and make polygon number the ID
  polys <- list()
  for(j in seq_along(cp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons)) {
    polys[[j]] <- Polygons(list(cp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[j]]),j)
  }
  cp <- SpatialPolygons(polys)
  cp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(cp, data.frame(id=seq_along(cp)))

  # group by elev (replicate ids)
  # ids = sapply(slot(cl, "lines"), slot, "ID")
  # lens = sapply(1:length(cl), function(i) length(cl[i,]@lines[[1]]@Lines))

  ## cut the raster by levels
  rc <- cut(r, breaks=plevels)

  ## loop through each polygon, create internal buffer, select points and define overlap with raster
  cat("Adding attributes to polygons...\n")
  l <- character(length(cp))
  for(j in seq_along(cp)) {
    p <- cp[cp$id==j,] 
    bp <- gBuffer(p, width = -max(res(r))) # use a negative buffer to obtain internal points
    if(!is.null(bp)) {
      xy <- SpatialPoints(coordinates(bp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]))[1]
      l[j] <- llevels[raster::extract(rc,xy)]
    } 
    else { 
      xy <- coordinates(gCentroid(p)) # buffer will not be calculated for smaller polygons, so grab centroid
      l[j] <- llevels[raster::extract(rc,xy)]
    }
  }

  ## assign level to each polygon
  cp$level <- factor(l, levels=llevels)
  cp$min <- plevels[-length(plevels)][cp$level]
  cp$max <- plevels[-1][cp$level]  
  cp <- cp[!is.na(cp$level),] # discard small polygons that did not capture a raster point
  df <- unique(cp@data[,c("level","min","max")]) # to be used after holes are defined
  df <- df[order(df$min),]
  row.names(df) <- df$level
  llevels <- df$level

  ## define depressions in higher levels (ie holes)
  cat("Defining holes...\n")
  spolys <- list()
  p <- cp[cp$level==llevels[1],] # add deepest layer
  p <- gUnaryUnion(p)
  spolys[[1]] <- Polygons(p@polygons[[1]]@Polygons, ID=llevels[1])
  for(i in seq(length(llevels)-1)) {
    p1 <- cp[cp$level==llevels[i+1],] # upper layer
    p2 <- cp[cp$level==llevels[i],] # lower layer
    x <- numeric(length(p2)) # grab one point from each of the deeper polygons
    y <- numeric(length(p2))
    id <- numeric(length(p2))
    for(j in seq_along(p2)) {
      xy <- coordinates(p2@polygons[[j]]@Polygons[[1]])[1,]
      x[j] <- xy[1]; y[j] <- xy[2]
      id[j] <- as.numeric(p2@polygons[[j]]@ID)
    }
    xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(x,y), data.frame(id=id))
    holes <- over(xy, p1)$id
    holes <- xy$id[which(!is.na(holes))]
    if(length(holes)>0) {
      p2 <- p2[p2$id %in% holes,] # keep the polygons over the shallower polygon
      p1 <- gUnaryUnion(p1) # simplify each group of polygons
      p2 <- gUnaryUnion(p2)
      p <- gDifference(p1, p2) # cut holes in p1      
    } else { p <- gUnaryUnion(p1) }
    spolys[[i+1]] <- Polygons(p@polygons[[1]]@Polygons, ID=llevels[i+1]) # add level 
  }
  cp <- SpatialPolygons(spolys, pO=seq_along(llevels), proj4string=CRS(proj4string(r))) # compile into final object

  ## make polygons exclusive (i.e. no overlapping)
  cpx = gDifference(cp[1,], cp[2,], id=cp[1,]@polygons[[1]]@ID)
  for(i in 2:(length(cp)-1)) cpx = spRbind(cpx, gDifference(cp[i,], cp[i+1,], id=cp[i,]@polygons[[1]]@ID))
  cp = spRbind(cpx, cp[length(cp),])

  ## it's a wrap
  cp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(cp, df)
  cat("Done!")
  cp
}
```

Comment: This came so darn close to working for me, yet some of the contour lines don't close properly and so just become floating lines instead of their own polygons.

Comment: A thousand curses