# How to get contour lines around the grids in R-raster?

Tags: r, r-raster

Having a raster in R, how can I draw a contour line *around* the grids (not joining the centers or anything else, really following the boundaries of the grids) having some value (or identified by some mask)?

The following example shows how to get the contour lines around areas with value 0.6: how to do the same but with the lines following the borders of the grids? 
The function should return an object to add to a plot (as a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` for `rasterToContour`), and adjacent grids should be included in one single contour line (i.e., only the outer boundaries of a polygon should be drawn). I couldn't find the solution with `rasterToPolygons` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379828/how-does-one-turn-contour-lines-into-filled-contours) for a visual aspect, but it didn't help me here).

```
set.seed(2)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
r[r>0.6] <- 0.6
rc <- rasterToContour(r, levels=c(0.6))
plot(r)
plot(rc, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use a combination of `clump()` and `rasterToPolygons()`:

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)  ## For dissolve = TRUE in rasterToPolygons()

## Recreate your data
set.seed(2)
r <- raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))   
plot(r)

## Compute and then plot polygons surrounding cells with values greater than 0.6
SP <- rasterToPolygons(clump(r > 0.6), dissolve = TRUE)
plot(SP, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Josh O'Brien, works very fine. In case useful for others: my initial attempts actually failed likely because I was working in a quite heavy R session with many packages loaded (incl. for spatial analysis); I didn't receive a clear error message when using `rasterToPolygons` and `dissolve=TRUE`. Under a new R session, an explicit error message appeared that lead me to re-install and reload the `rgeos` package, and things worked much better with `rasterToPolygons` - including the nice solution above.