# R - convert SpatialLines into raster

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, r-sp

In R, we can take a `raster` and turn it into a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` with the function `rasterToCountour`:

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
x <- rasterToContour(r)
class(x)

[1] "SpatialLinesDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

spplot(x)
```

[image]

#### Within R, is there a way to do the opposite? Something like `contourToRaster`?

We can simply grab the field values associated with each point along the line, but I'm looking for something more general that interpolates between the lines and produces a full raster over a defined domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
x <- rasterToContour(r)
```

You can rasterize the values. In this case after extracting them from the factor labels first.

```
x$value <- as.numeric(as.character(x$level))
rr <- rasterize(x, r, "value")
```

And then extract the cell values and interpolate these

```
xyz <- rasterToPoints(rr)
```

(if you want to skip rasterize and rasterToPoints (as mikoontz suggests) you could instead do

```
#g <- geom(x) 
#xyz = cbind(g[, c("x", "y")], x$value[g[,1]])
```

at the expense of a more complex model)

Now interpolate, for example with Tps

```
library(fields) 
tps <- Tps(xyz[,1:2], xyz[,3])
p <- raster(r)
p <- interpolate(p, tps)

m <- mask(p, r)
plot(m)
```

Comment: Excellent. I like the flexibility of this approach because once you have points there are a variety of interpolation methods at hand (e.g. - TPS, IDW, Kriging, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Do you only have access to the object created by `rasterToContour()`?

If you still have access to the original raster, you can create the contours as complete polygons first (instead of creating them as lines). Then the "contourToRaster"-like function is just `rasterize()` (or `fasterize()`).

Some code borrowed from here: [How does one turn contour lines into filled contours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379828/how-does-one-turn-contour-lines-into-filled-contours)

```
library(fasterize)

rc <- cut(r, breaks= 10)
cut_vals <- cut(r[], breaks = 10, dig.lab = 5)

pols <- rasterToPolygons(rc, dissolve=T) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

r_template <- raster(pols, res = res(r))
back_to_raster <- fasterize(pols, r_template, field = "layer") 

par(oma = c(0, 0, 0, 5))
plot(back_to_raster, legend = FALSE)
plot(back_to_raster, legend.only=TRUE, legend.width = 1,
     axis.args=list(at=1:nlevels(cut_vals),
                    labels=levels(cut_vals)))
```

Produces:

[image]

EDIT:

I like Robert's approach to this if you want to interpolate. I'd skip the `rasterize()` step, which can be pretty slow, in favor of casting the multilinestrings to points directly:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(fields)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
x <- rasterToContour(r)
class(x)

x_sf <- x %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% st_cast("MULTIPOINT") %>% st_cast("POINT")

tps <- Tps(x = st_coordinates(x_sf), Y = as.numeric(as.character(x_sf$level)))

p <- interpolate(r, tps) %>% mask(r)

plot(p)
```

[image]

Note that both of these methods rely access to the original `raster` object.

Comment: The goal is to go from lines -> points -> interpolation -> field. I like your approach because it's a bit faster. I think this answer will be improved for people reading in the future by removing the first chunk of code and plot.